# Подскажите делаю запрос изменения данных в БД - но меняет не так

Tags: php, sql, массивы

В БД хранятся новости сайта. Есть поле `data`, в ней хранятся даты новостей в виде - 03.05.16 (дата/месяц/год), с помощью кода переворачиваю строку в - год/месяц/дата - сам понимаю что в коде ошибка (не хватает цикла прохода по БД) - но я не могу логически понять, где он должен быть, т.к. при выполнении php-скрипта, он берет дату из первой строки данных и переписывает дату всем новостям, а не одной отдельной, а надо чтоб брал дату каждой новости и переворачивал. Подскажите, как это сделать? Вот мой код

```
<?php   
$select_query = "SELECT data FROM NEWS";
// Запуск запроса
$result = mysql_query($select_query);
if ($result) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);


$data = $row['data'];
$array_string = explode('.', $data);
$Mass = array_reverse($array_string);
$string = implode('.', $Mass);

$select_query = "UPDATE `NEWS` SET `data`='$string'";
// Запуск запроса
$result = mysql_query($select_query) or die('Ошибка!!!)');
if ($result) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
$data = $row['data'];
}}

?>
```

**Обновление**

Новости парсятся с помощью программы DATACOL, которая позволяет сохранять даты только в формате дата/мес/год, и сохраняет в виде строки, по другому никак, потому мне и нужен цикл прохода всем полям data в БД, и изменению порядка даты в каждой, а если вы имеете ввиду запрос к БД ORDER BY то он тут не катит т.к. БД фильтрует по убыванию только строки например 16.02.01 а не 01.02.16

Comment: Вообще тут код не нужен. Это делается одним запросом SQL. но есть более серьезный вопрос, зачем вы вообще переворачиваете дату, она у вас в виде строки что ли хранится ? Дату _надо_ хранить в поле типа date или datetime, тогда ее и получать можно будет сразу в любом удобном формате

Comment: Да, и кстати цикл то правильный у вас. Только вот update, без условия where обновляет _все_ записи в базе. Вам надо было бы выбирать еще id записи и обновлять только ее update ... where id=$id. Но вам там уже написали правильный вариант одним запросом. Изучайте SQL, он позволяет гораздо больше, чем просто select всей таблицы. Если для обработки данных из базы с целью вернуть их обратно в базу приходится делать цикл - вы не правы, SQL может сделать это гораздо быстрее и гораздо короче по коду, чем php

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Эту операцию можно выполнить одним SQL-запросом

```
UPDATE NEWS
SET data = CONCAT(SUBSTR(data, 7, 2), '.', SUBSTR(data, 4, 2), '.', SUBSTR(data, 1, 2));
```